# Redis auto update cache

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I am using Django-redis cache and I am saving my data in a redis cache but When I update my database i don't find updated data in redis cache.

My code is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import students
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.cache import cache


class UserListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        data = cache.get('alldata')

        if not data:

            data = students.objects.values('cache_id', 'username',  'email')
            cache.set('alldata', data)
```

In settings.py  I have following items in middleware class:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',   
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

Is there any way to automatically update redis cache?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Os

Comment: You can run `redis-cli -p <port_num> -n 1` and then `flushdb` in the new prompt and then `exit`. This will clear the redis cache and update the changes.

Comment: For updating the cache value is it necessary to delete the cache? 
Is there is any alternative to update existing values of cache (by simply adding new values to existing one's)?